# Apache Kylin: How to use '!=' in queries?

Tags: sql, apache, kylin

I got a short question on Apache kylin (version 1.5.3). I have built a cube successfully. Now I want to  use the 'insight' tab of kylin to submit some queries. I have a table with two columns (id[varchar], abc[int]).

Queries like

```
select id, abc
from table
where abc = 12;
```

are working fine. But

```
select id, abc
from table
where abc != 12;
```

returns an error:

> Lexical error at line 3, column 11. Encountered: "!" (33), after : ""

Does anyone knows the right lexical term of 'not'?

Thank you in advance,
Søren

Comment: Did you try **<>** ?

Comment: I did not. Its working. I knew this was too easy... Thank you @ Pham X. Bach

Comment: np, some db don't support **!=** operator. nice day to you.

Comment: And `not` sometimes is usefull

Comment: 'not' is returning the error message: Was expecting one of: "DISTINCT" ... "NOT" "DISTINCT" ... "A" ... "NOT" ... "NOT" "NULL" ... "NOT" "TRUE" ... "NOT" "FALSE" ... "NOT" "UNKNOWN" ... "NULL" ... "TRUE" ... "FALSE" ... "UNKNOWN" ...